# В чем разница между ssh ... 'bash -s' < "command" и ssh ... "command"?

Tags: bash

Скрипт собирает папку, где в числе прочего находится скрипт `install.sh`. Папка закидывается на устройство и этот скрипт там должен запускаться с параметром, указывающим на каталог с файлами для установки.

От предшественника мне досталось много скриптов именно с `bash -s` и подачей данных на вход, и они работают. Я сделал по аналогии, но почему-то *неработающий* фрагмент, отвечающий за это действие:

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@$IP \
'bash -s' < "/home/firmware/$dir/install.sh /home/firmware/$dir"
```

Я знаю, что `sshpass -p` нехорошо, мой вопрос про другое.
В общем, этот шаг приводит к ошибке:

`cannot open /home/firmware/firmware-blackbox-001_000-17.07.2019-13.58.58/install.sh /home/firmware/firmware-blackbox-001_000-17.07.2019-13.58.58: No such file`

Скрипт не видит файл, но он там есть!

Методом тыка я нашел решение:

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@$IP \
"/home/firmware/$dir/install.sh /home/firmware/$dir"
```

Почему тот скрипт не работает, а этот работает? В чем разница?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом варианте перенаправление ввода (`< "/home/firmware/$dir/install.sh /home/firmware/$dir") обрабатывается на локальной машине локальной оболочкой. И так как файл лежит на удалённом хосте, локальный шелл справедливо жалуется, что не может его найти.

Во втором же варианте на удалённом хосте запускается вся команда `"bash /home/firmware/firmware-blackbox-001.../install.sh /home/firmware/firmware-blackbox-001..."` так как если бы она была запущена через системный вызов `system()` т.е. с разделением её на аргументы там где есть пробелы итп.

Собственно чтобы в первом случае команда работала желанным образом достаточно просто включить перенаправление ввода под кавычки:

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@$IP \
'bash -s' "</home/firmware/$dir/install.sh /home/firmware/$dir"
```